# How can I automatically update an int value in a label?

Tags: c#

So here's my situation, I have a form (Stats), with a bunch of labels containing integer values related to the players attributes IE: strength, agility, dexterity, etc. The thing
I'm trying to figure out how to do is to have these values updated and passed to the corresponding forms automatically each time the player's stats change.

Say for example the players strength is 10, and then he equips an item that increases his strength by 5, how would I get the value in the corresponding attribute label to update automatically and equal 15?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you using winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 2):

First, make your data class that contains the strength, agility and such implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) (or use a [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com) for this)

Then [databind](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html) the label to this:

```
control.Data1Label.DataBindings.Add("Text", fighter, "Strength");
```

Comment: About PostSharp: [example for INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/ui#data-binding) if you'd like to try something different. That way you can just add an attribute to your data class and be done with the INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: This is using WinFoms btw! With WPF you want to go the DependencyProperty way and bind from XAML.

Answer (score 0):

MVC architecture. make the view (your form) to observe the Modele (your data class). When a modification happen in the data. The modele fire an event (or you could implement the observer pattern on your own) to make the the view update it data.